# Insert several columns instead of one existing to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, one-hot-encoding

I have a question  - how to insert multiple (for example 3) columns to the DataFrame on the location of an existing column? In other words, I had a column with some categorical values which I encode with one-hot encoding - as a result, I obtained 3 new columns. Now, I want to drop the original column and insert resulting columns on its location (and not to the end of data frame). Any ideas of how to do it efficiently? I'll appreciate any help.

```
**df1 - Original datafarme** :

   col1 col2  col3
0   4    A    0.5
1   5    B    0.78
2   6    C    0.55
3   7    A    0.78

**df2 - created one-hot encoding of categorical col2** :

   col2_A col2_B  col2_C
0   1       0       0
1   0       1       0
2   0       0       1
3   1       0       0
```

How to insert columns of df2 to df1, instead of col2 to obtain:

```
**Updated df1**

   col1 col2_A col2_b col2_C  col3
0   4    1      0        0    0.5
1   5    0      1        0    0.78
2   6    0      0        1    0.55
3   7    1      0        0    0.78
```

Comment: if possible put the to be added `df` separately and use  `concat` or `join` or `merge` as per the requirement.

Comment: `df1.join(df2).drop(columns = 'col2').sort_index(axis = 1) ` 
isn't it simpler? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with any new columns in `df2` (not necessary starts with `col2`)

Use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for positions, so possible filter by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) values before and after column and then join together in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), last if necessary remove column:

```
val = 'col2'
p = df.columns.get_loc(val)

#possible solution for dummies, be free use your solution
#df2 = pd.get_dummies(df[val])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :p], df2, df.iloc[:, p:]], axis=1).drop(val, axis=1)
print (df)

   col1  A  B  C  col3
0     4  1  0  0  0.50
1     5  0  1  0  0.78
2     6  0  0  1  0.55
3     7  1  0  0  0.78
```

If prefixes are necessary:

```
val = 'col2'
p = df.columns.get_loc(val)
#possible solution for dummies, be free use your solution
#df2 = pd.get_dummies(df[[val]])
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :p], df2, df.iloc[:, p:]], axis=1).drop(val, axis=1)
print (df)

   col1  col2_A  col2_B  col2_C  col3
0     4       1       0       0  0.50
1     5       0       1       0  0.78
2     6       0       0       1  0.55
3     7       1       0       0  0.78
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) in [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) or another solution:

```
val = 'col2'
p = df.columns.get_loc(val)
#possible solution for dummies, be free use your solution
#df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.pop(val))
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :p], df2, df.iloc[:, p:]], axis=1)
print (df)

   col1  A  B  C  col3
0     4  1  0  0  0.50
1     5  0  1  0  0.78
2     6  0  0  1  0.55
3     7  1  0  0  0.78
```

Comment: the question is `How to insert columns of df2 to df1, instead of col2 to obtain:`

Answer (score 1):

use

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

then to drop that col_2 use

```
df_concat.drop(['col_2'], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if the indexes are aligned correctly use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to remove `col2` and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to order columns

```
df1.join(df2).drop(columns = 'col2').sort_index(axis = 1)

   col1  col2_A  col2_B  col2_C  col3
0     4       1       0       0  0.50
1     5       0       1       0  0.78
2     6       0       0       1  0.55
3     7       1       0       0  0.78
```

---

We can also use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) instead `pd.get_dummies`

```
new_df = (df1.join(df1.pivot_table(columns = 'col2',
                                   index = df1.index,
                                   aggfunc = 'size',
                                   fill_value = 0)
                      .add_prefix('col2_'))
              .drop(columns = 'col2')
              .sort_index(axis = 1))
print(new_df)
   col1  col2_A  col2_B  col2_C  col3
0     4       1       0       0  0.50
1     5       0       1       0  0.78
2     6       0       0       1  0.55
3     7       1       0       0  0.78
```

Comment: ????????? check output

Comment: Do you know the OP problem and the OP DataFrame? I'm starting to think so

Comment: OP already has df2, I have simply made a note that pivot_table also works for this case, but the question is not to get the `dummies`

Comment: Also changed my solution, thanks for pointing it.